# How do I establish 2 way communication to my script that I'm sending through ssh?

Tags: bash, ksh

I'm trying to establish two-way communication between a Windows box (with a bash cli) and a qnx box (with a ksh cli, though currently I'm using a linux VM with ksh98 to test with) over ssh using scripts.

I can't seem to get the redirects quite right though.  Here is my simple setup:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

cleanup() {
  exec >&$SSH_STDIN- ; rm ssh_stdin
  exec <&$SSH_STDOUT-; rm ssh_stdout
  echo "Cleaned up."
}
trap 'cleanup' EXIT

mkfifo ssh_stdin ; exec  {SSH_STDIN}<>./ssh_stdin
mkfifo ssh_stdout; exec {SSH_STDOUT}<>./ssh_stdout

echo "SSH_STDIN:  $SSH_STDIN"
echo "SSH_STDOUT: $SSH_STDOUT"
repeat() { echo "$2"; echo "$2" >&$1; }

fn() {
  sleep 5
  echo AWAKE! >&2
  set +o xtrace
  while read -u $SSH_STDOUT a b; do
    case "$a" in
      Hi!)             sleep 1; repeat $SSH_STDOUT "Ho!" ;;
      and-away-we-go!) sleep 1; repeat $SSH_STDOUT "quit";;
      *) echo "UNRECOGNIZED: $a $b";;
    esac
  done
}
fn&

ssh user@127.0.0.1 -p 2022  '
. /etc/profile  # Used to setup path
repeat() { echo "$2"; echo "$2" >&$1; }
repeat 2 "Hi!"
while read a b; do
  case "$a" in
    Ho! ) sleep 1; repeat "and-away-we-go!";;
    quit ) exit 0;;
    * ) echo "UNRECOGINZED: $a $b";;
  esac
done
' >&$SSH_STDIN <&$SSH_STDOUT
```

I feel that I'm close. What am I doing wrong?  Maybe this can be done without using named FIFOs?

#### EDIT

This is the output:

```
$ ./test-writer.sh
SSH_STDIN:  11
SSH_STDOUT: 12
user@127.0.0.1's password:
Hi!
AWAKE!
./test-writer.sh: line 21: read: read error: 12: Communication error on send
```

It then hangs and after I press Ctrl-C:

```
./test-writer.sh: line 6: echo: write error: Communication error on send
```

Here it is with `bash -x`

```
$ bash -x ./test-writer.sh
+ trap cleanup EXIT
+ mkfifo ssh_stdin
+ exec
+ mkfifo ssh_stdout
+ exec
+ echo 'SSH_STDIN:  11'
SSH_STDIN:  11
+ echo 'SSH_STDOUT: 12'
SSH_STDOUT: 12
+ fn
+ ssh user@127.0.0.1 -p 2022 '
. /etc/profile  # Used to setup path
repeat() { echo "$2"; echo "$2" >&$1; }
repeat 2 "Hi!"
while read a b; do
  case "$a" in
    Ho! ) sleep 1; repeat "and-away-we-go!";;
    quit ) exit 0;;
    * ) echo "UNRECOGINZED: $a $b";;
  esac
done
'
+ sleep 5
user@127.0.0.1's password:
Hi!
+ echo 'AWAKE!'
AWAKE!
+ set +o xtrace
./test-writer.sh: line 21: read: read error: 12: Communication error on send
```

and after it hangs, I press Ctrl-C and get:

```
+ cleanup
+ exec
+ rm ssh_stdin
+ exec
+ rm ssh_stdout
+ echo 'Cleaned up.'
./test-writer.sh: line 6: echo: write error: Communication error on send
```

Although I have a solution using `coproc`, I would like to know why this solution isn't working.

Comment: do you have `coproc`? `trap 'cleanup' SIGINT` Use `EXIT`. That way it will always cleanup. So what is not working? What _happens_? Does anything show up? Please try with `set -x` and post the output.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I've updated with adding in the remote loop `set -o xtrace` and called it with `bash -x`.  I'm looking into `coproc` as I've not heard of it before.  I also didn't hear of `EXIT` to be added to trap.  Had to look that one up.  That's very useful. Thx.

Comment: @KamilCuk, oh that `coproc` was so close!  It doesn't redirect `stderr` though, which is a deal breaker.   Why did the devs fall short of just finishing off the code! ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a hint by @KamilCuk about using `coproc` I was able to come up with an answer which is much less unwieldly.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

cleanup() {
  # Do I even need this?
  exec <&${ssh_fd[0]}- >&${ssh_fd[1]}-
  echo "Cleaned up."
}
trap 'cleanup' EXIT

coproc ssh_fd {
  ssh user@127.0.0.1 -p 2022  '
  . /etc/profile  # Used to setup path
  repeat() { echo "$2"; echo "$2" >&$1; }
  repeat 2 "Hi!"
  while read a b; do
    case "$a" in
      Ho! ) sleep 1; repeat 2 "and-away-we-go!";;
      quit ) exit 0;;
      * ) echo "UNRECOGINZED: .$a. .$b." >&2;;
    esac
  done
  '
}

repeat() { echo "$2"; echo "$2" >&$1; }

fn() {
  set +o xtrace
  while read -u ${ssh_fd[0]} a b; do
    case "$a" in
      Hi!)             sleep 1; repeat ${ssh_fd[1]}  "Ho!" ;;
      and-away-we-go!) sleep 1; repeat ${ssh_fd[1]}  "quit";;
      *) echo "UNRECOGNIZED: $a $b";;
    esac
  done
}
fn
```

Output:

```
$  ./test-writer.sh
user@127.0.0.1's password:
Hi!
Ho!
and-away-we-go!
quit
```

I didn't actually change anything in the code, just deleted and moved stuff around.  I was right!  I was almost there!  Thx @KamilCuk!

Still, although I have this solution, I would like to know why the original one didn't work.  I think it should, and I'll accept those answers if they figure it out.

Actually, still looking for a solution.  I'm not sure why the devs fell short of redirecting all of the handles, INCLUDING STDERR! *sigh*